# High/Critical Security Risk in (platform frameworks base android-9.0.0_r10) - CVE-2019-9468

Tags: android, security, android-source

I'm using Black Duck tool for scanning security risk, license risk, etc. Starting January, 2020, a new Security Risk appeared in the component [Android - platform - frameworks - base android-9.0.0_r10 with android platform-external-chromium-webview:android-9.0.0_r10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf2V9.png) with this identifier [CVE-2019-9468](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPLlo.png), [please find enclosed all the screenshots].

Looking deeper inside the Black Duck platform, I found this link https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel/2019-12-01 that confirm this security risk. This bulletin describes the security patches for devices, but ¿how to fix this in my code? Perhaps upgrading some libraries, upgrading the minimum SDK version from 21 to 22, upgrading the buildToolVersion to 29.0.3, upgrading API level to 29, excluding module: "platform-external-chromium-webview" in my .gradle. I tried all these options, and they didn't work. Only with the minimum SDK version 28 and API level 29 works, but that is not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this risk, you need to upgrade the version of **gradle-wrapper.properties** and the root **buil.gradle** of your project.

***build.gradle***

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
    ....
}
```

***gradle-wrapper.properties***

```
......
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```